Ошибка cors при обращении к файлу


const photoPromise = fetch("https://cdn.vanderbilt.edu/vu-wp0/wp-content/uploads/sites/59/2019/03/27130027/complex-300x180.png")
    .then((response) => response.blob())
    .then((blob) => {
        const file = new File([blob], "image", { type: blob.type });
        return Promise.resolve(file);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        return error;
    });

new Promise((resolve) => resolve(photoPromise))
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });



приходит:
TypeError: Failed to fetch
Access to fetch at 'https://cdn.vanderbilt.edu/vu-wp0/wp-content/uploads/sites/59/2019/03/27130027/complex-300x180.png' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

VM581:460
   GET https://cdn.vanderbilt.edu/vu-wp0/wp-content/uploads/sites/59/2019/03/27130027/complex-300x180.png net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)


у сервера не стоит соответствующих заголовков, поэтому браузер блокирует запрос с соответствующей ошибкой

Попробуй подставить в <head> твоего index.html строку:
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />

Или использовать:
fetch(url, {
    mode: 'no-cors',
})

